# Oauth generate signature without any package

Tags: php, oauth

I have to integrate a web application with an API. The API uses OAuth 1.0 to authorize the requests. I have gone through the documentation at http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/. I have followed all the steps to generate the signature But the server always returns the message "invalid signature".

However, if I put my consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access token secret in POSTMAN. Then the signature that is generated by the POSTMAN is accepted by the server.

That means there is nothing wrong with the server. The problem is in the code that I am using to generate the signature.

Here is the code that I have written after reading the documentation to generate the tokens.

```
$consumer_key = '__MY_CONSUMER_KEY__';
$secret = '__MY__SECRET_KEY__';

$url = 'http://oauth.example.com/oauth/initiate';
$parameters = 'oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key='.$consumer_key.'&oauth_nonce='.dechex(time()).'&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp='.time().'&oauth_version=1.0';


$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', 'GET&'.rawurlencode($url).'&'.rawurlencode($parameters), $secret, true));
$signed_request = $url.'?'.$parameters.'&oauth_signature='.$signature.PHP_EOL;
```

I know there are some predefined the packages available for this But I want to know what is the actual logic to generate the signature for OAuth 1.0.

Comment: Suggest you start by following the basic example with the values given there, that should make it easier to verify whether you got the correct Signature Base String or not: https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#sig_base_example

Comment: I am not using the parameter "oauth_token"

Comment: So what? Then _add_ it, for _testing_ purposes, to see if you generate the correct string in the first place. (Would make more sense anyway IMHO if you implemented this in a more flexible way, like provide an array of the parameters to a function, that then takes care of stuff like the sorting etc., rather than hard-coding this for the specific set of parameters used right now …)

Comment: @misorude Ok I did create the base_string and it is exactly same as generated in the documentation.

Comment: And the signature value you get with that as input string is also the same as in the example?

Comment: Yes the signature is also same as it is in the documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182367/discussion-between-amarjit-singh-and-misorude).